# Zoom in on Excel 2010 print preview

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any way to zoom in when in print preview mode for Excel 2010? Many textboxes don't print as displayed (not WYSIWYG) and sometimes the print preview zoomed out is too small to notice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can zoom *manually*, but there is a small button at the bottom-right called 'zoom to page' and that basically zooms it right in:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

(this is 2013, but the button should still be there)